# Create PHP collection class that extends an array

Tags: php, arrays, class, collections, spl

I am in process of writing a class which contains a collection of other objects.  I will create a method to move an element in the collection from one position to another, another to determine what has been changed, etc.

Instead of starting from scratch, is there some pre-built class which I should be extending?  I expect there is a [spl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) which I should be using, but I am very new to this part of PHP, and am not sure where to start. I recently came across [class.arrayobject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) but it doesn't appear to be something which is extended.

```
class Collection
{
    protected $stack=[];
    private $originalStack;

    public function __construct(array $nodes=[]) { //$nodes is an array of Node objects
        $this->stack=$nodes;
        $this->originalStack=array_merge(array(), $nodes);    //Arrays not passed by reference but the objects are!
    }

    public function getChanges(){
        $this->stack;
    }

    public function getPositionChanges($prop){
        return array_udiff_assoc($this->stack, $this->originalStack,
            function ($stack, $originalStack) {
                return is_numeric($stack->$prop) && is_numeric($originalStack->$prop)
                ?$stack->$prop - $originalStack->$prop
                :strcmp($stack->$prop, $originalStack->$prop);
            }
        );
    }

    public function getAll(){
        $this->stack;
    }

    public function getByPosition(int $position){
        $this->stack[$position];
    }

    public function getPropertyByPosition(int $position, $property){
        return $this->stack[$position]->$property;  //Uses __get
    }

    public function add(Node $elem){
        $this->stack[]=$elem;
    }

    public function delete(int $position){
        if(!isset($this->stack[$position])) throw new CollectionException('Index does not exist');
        unset($this->stack[$position]);
        $this->stack=$stack[]=array_values($this->stack);
    }

    public function move(int $initialPosition, int $finalPosition){
        if(!isset($this->stack[$initialPosition]) || !isset($this->stack[$finalPosition])) throw new CollectionException('Index does not exist');
        $node=$this->stack[$initialPosition];
        unset($this->stack[$initialPosition]);
        array_splice($this->stack, $finalPosition, 0, $node);
        $this->stack=array_values($this->stack);
        //?? return $this->stack;
    }

    public function update(int $position, $property, $value){
        if(!isset($this->stack[$position])) throw new CollectionException('Index does not exist');
        $this->stack[$position]->$property=$value;  //Uses __set
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you'll probably want to look at `ArrayAccess` interface instead: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: @PhilCross  Ah, I think you are right.  These interfaces are all new territory for me.  Exciting but a little daunting.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Know of any good tutorials that explain the "big picture"?  The manual is great for details, but I sometime have a hard time deriving the concept from it.  Thanks

Comment: Personally, I use a mixture of videos and looking at source code of other projects. Laracasts.com offers great videos for PHP and Laravel (PHP framework), it explains some core concepts, patterns etc really well. They offer a bunch of free videos as well. Highly worth it.
As for looking at source code, I use Laravel a lot, and love diving into the source code. It can be pretty complicated, but if you keep with it, you start understanding patterns and design choices better.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ds-collection.php  http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Comment: @Eakethet  Do you know if arrayaccess somehow extends these interfaces?